# Save content of a variable in a list, not the pointer to a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm very new to flutter, so please bear with me. Any help is much appreciated!

Some background: The goal is to have a text where each word is clickable and will be highlighted. Also, the containing sentence should be highlighted (somewhat differently). In the end this is supposed to become a language learning app, if that's of any interest.
So my idea was to have some nested TextSpans that I can then style differently. I didn't get that far though, because I'm unable to create the correct list of lists of words. Basically what happens is that I end up with the X times the last sentence of the text.

Here is the function that is supposed to build the nested TextSpans:
(Sentence is a simple class which holds one whole sentence, as well as its individual words).

```
List<TextSpan> TextSpanSentences(List sentences) {
    List<Sentence> listOfSentences = [];
    List<TextSpan> listOfWords = [];
    List<TextSpan> listOfTextSpans = [];

    for (String sentence in sentences) {
      listOfSentences.add(Sentence(sentence: sentence));
    }

    for (Sentence sentence in listOfSentences) {
      listOfWords.clear();

      for (String word in sentence.words) {
        listOfWords.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: '$word ',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20, height: 1.8),
            recognizer: wordTapRecognizer(word),
          ),
        );
      }
      listOfTextSpans.add(TextSpan(
        children: listOfWords,
      ));
    }
    return listOfTextSpans;
  }
```

What I thought I would get was something like "Sentence One Sentence Two .... Last Sentence"
But what I get is "Last Sentence Last Sentence Last Sentence .... Last Sentence".

To me it seems like where I'm adding the listOfWords to the listOfTextSpans, it doesn't actually save the content of the variable to the list, but only a pointer to the 'listOfWords' variable, whose content changes after each loop.
How could I approach this differently?

Thanks a lot!
vv

Comment: Everything in Dart is an object.  Variables always store references to objects.  If you want two separate objects, you will need to explicitly construct two separate objects, possibly with one copying the other.

Comment: Thanks for the hint jamesdlin. Do you have an example how I would do this in this context?

Comment: Change `children: listOfWords` to `children: listOfWords.toList()` to create a copy of the `List`.  Or just move `List<TextSpan> listOfWords = [];` into the loop body (and then you won't need to clear it on each iteration).